# How to create a Kibana Visualization to show jobs failing over last 7 days

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

My app executes about 3 to 4 million jobs every day. Jobs are scheduled with the same unique ID and every job has a completion status representing success or failure. I would like to create a kibana visualization that shows the jobs that are failing continuously for more than 7 days. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm also looking for similar problem, did you manage to find one already?

Answer (score 2):

> Select term as failure in **split bars** section in x-axis
>
> Use **Range** option in **split chart** field and can  select date range as one week as u asked earlier